# Should I use template tags or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django, performance, django-models, django-templates

I have a website that provides distance and speed data and the user can specify which units they want the data to be displayed in. Their user preferences are stored in a user profile table.

Currently the data is stored in meters and meters per second in the database.

When it comes to displaying the data to the user is it better to use a template tag to convert each piece of data into the correct units or use a template tag once to return the convertipn factor and then use JavaScript to convert each piece of data.

Currently there the template has 20 data points that need converting but that could grow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your web page in django? (I saw the tag). If it is, it's better to proccess and  convert everything in your view (and easier). And you just send the right context to the template.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll go this route as I can test the resultant conversion wihtin Django whereas the other way I can't

Answer (score 0):

Well I had a think and implemented the conversion in the view but it didn't seem very DRY so I did a bit more searching and found out about model methods which seem to solve the problem very well.

As a bit of an explanation; each track has an owner. Each owner has a profile which then has a distance unit. Each distance unit has a conversion factor to go from km (the unit all data is stored in) to that unit. The profile also has a boolean field to say if speed should be showed as pace (true) or units per hour (false).

here is an excerpt from my models.py:

```
class gpxTrack(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-start']

    track = models.MultiLineStringField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    distance = models.DecimalField("total moving distance in kilometers", blank=True, null=True, max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    average_speed = models.DecimalField("average moving speed in kilometers per hour", blank=True, null=True, max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.start.strftime("%a %p %-d %B %Y")

    def distance_user_units(self):
        return round(self.distance * self.owner.profile.distance_unit.conversion_factor,2)

    def speed_user_units(self):
        pace_conversion_factor = 60 if self.owner.profile.pace else 1
        return round( pace_conversion_factor / (self.average_speed * self.owner.profile.distance_unit.conversion_factor) ,2)
```

this method is now called from the template as below:

```
        {% for track in top5distance %}
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'dashboard:track_detail' pk=track.pk %}">{{ track.start }}</a>
            <span class="pull-right">
                {{ track.speed_user_units }} 
                : {{ track.distance_user_units }} 
            </span>
        </li>
        {% empty %}
```